# Jqgrid Grouping collapse whole group rows

Tags: jqgrid

If the first group displayed, contains say more than 10 rows and 'rowNum:10' without rowList option on UI. 
On collapse of first group, how to collapse the entire group rows irrespective of pages in pager and bring the next group to be displayed on first page, if the grid height is fixed.

I have copied the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8urj2mpm/1/) and modified to have more rows in first group 'test'

Also is it possible to display summary only at end of group, not on bottom of each pager page

```
{pager: "#plist486",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'name',
    grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['name'],
        groupSummary : [true],
        groupColumnShow : [true],
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
        groupCollapse : false,
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        showSummaryOnHide: true,
        groupDataSorted : true
    }}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to change the property `groupCollapse` of `groupingView` option to `true` and examine the grid with Developer Tools of IE/Chrome. You will see *all the rows*, but now the collapsed rows hidden (`style="display:none"`). After understanding the fact it will be clear that you can implement your requirements only if you increase the value of `rowNum`. You can try to do some additional customization using `onClickGroup`  callback or `jqGridGroupingClickGroup` event handler.

Comment: thanks Oleg, I'll try to play with it. Is there any way to get the collapse event for group

Comment: You are welcome! `onClickGroup` callback or `jqGridGroupingClickGroup` event handler will be called/triggered on collapse/expand. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A315935+%5Bjqgrid%5D+onClickGroup) three old answers with demos which uses the callback.